# How can i make the camera to follow the player from behind?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;       //Public variable to store a reference to the player game object


    private Vector3 offset;         //Private variable to store the offset distance between the player and camera

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Calculate and store the offset value by getting the distance between the player's position and camera's position.
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // LateUpdate is called after Update each frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Set the position of the camera's transform to be the same as the player's, but offset by the calculated offset distance.
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
    }
}
```

If i will use only the line:

```
transform.LookAt(player.transform);
```

It will rotate the camera according to the player movement but the camera will stay in place.
When i'm using also the line:

```
transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
```

The camera will move but now it will be in front of the player not behind following it. I want the camera to LookAt and to follow from behind.

Comment: Have you tried `-offset` instead of `+offset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the offset in the player's local space. You can either use vector math (for example, `player.transform.position - player.transform.forward * distance`) or have a reference empty GameObject in the player's hierarchy that serves as the camera's position target.

Answer (score 1):

check this script, this will follow the target with permanent lookat vector of the camera, then if you would like to follow forward vector of the target need to add additional logic to the script :)

```
public class CameraFollowController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject target;
        int offsetDistance = 10;
        int offsetHeight = 5;
        Vector3 targetLookAtVec;

        void Start()
        {
            Camera.main.transform.position = target.transform.position 
                - target.transform.forward * offsetDistance
                + target.transform.up * offsetHeight;
            Camera.main.transform.LookAt(target.transform);
            targetLookAtVec = Camera.main.transform.position - target.transform.position;
        }
        void LateUpdate()
        {
            Camera.main.transform.position = target.transform.position + targetLookAtVec;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct; to make the camera follow the player you must:

1. as @apk suggested, create an empty game object in the hierarchy view and name it "Player",
2. add both the player and the camera to the empty game object.

When you create the empty game object, do not forget to reset its position to 0, 0, 0.

I hope this helps.